# How to change white background of an included PDF to transparent

Tags: graphics, pdf, color, backgrounds, transparency

I have an external 100 pages PDF document (not created by pdflatex) that I `\includegraphics` page-wise into a beamer presentation. The external PDF document employs white as page color, but I need the background to be transparent.

Ideally, this would be an option one could pass to `\includegraphics` – which I doubt to exist. However, I would also be open for some process involving external tools (`pdftk`, `pdfjam`, ImageMagick, Acrobat...).

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure about turning anything to transparent in a PDF. PDF is not an image format, so I guess the only way is to remove the background object entriely from the pages. You could do that manually (on every page) with Acrobat professional (and probably also some free pdf editors), but if you're lucky, the following may work:

1. Convert your PDF into something readable with `qpdf -qdf file.pdf  file-redable.pdf`.
2. Look in there for the background object. (Luck needed at this point) More often than not, it will look somewhat like 
   this:

   ```
   10 765.75 591.75 -729.75 re
   f
   ```

   That is, a filled rectangle large enough to cover the whole page.
3. Experimentally remove it.
4. Fix the resulting pdf with `fix-qdf file-redable.pdf`.
5. Try whether it worked ;-)
6. If you found the right object to remove, you can remove it in all places simultaneously with `sed`, for instance.

Comment: Aye. This may also be possible with `Inkscape` or `Illustrator`.

Comment: Thanks Stephan! While I managed to find the MacPorts package for `qpdf`, I have not yet found a tool named `fix-pdf`. Searching for it reveals a commercial Windows-only tool (http://www.fixpdf.org), which, however, does not look like being a command-line utility. Is that the one you refer too?

Comment: @Daniel Argh, sorry. Typo. I meant `fix-qdf` which is part of the `qdf` bundle and responsible for fixing things like object tables after a "qdf" file has been edited.

Comment: :-) I have edited this also in your answer, so (after a while) we can delete these comments. As soon as I find some time I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not yet been able to find the background object. (The PDF in question is generated under Windows with OpenOffice 3.x from an OO presentation).

Comment: Thanks Stefan! I tried your solution---the result is good---but `file-readable.pdf` seems damaged: > qpdf --check file-readable.pdf WARNING: file-readable.pdf: file is damaged WARNING: file-readable.pdf (file position 62299): xref not found WARNING: file-readable.pdf: Attempting to reconstruct cross-reference table I looked up a little and found this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932012/how-to-generate-plain-text-source-code-pdf-examples-that-work-in-a-document-view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932012/how-to-generate-plain-text-source-code-pdf-examples-that-work-in-a-doc

Comment: @Jef Only replace the first character of the lines to be deleted by a percent character (comment char in PDF or PostScript). The byte count must not be changed.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the `qpdf` as suggested, and it worked for me with libreoffice generated pdf. I created a script to remove the background. 
It may or may not work depending on version, etc, and can damage your PDF, so use at your risk

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ] ; then
    echo "Use: $0 pdf_with_background.pdf"
    exit 1
fi

FILE="$1"
FILEQDF="$1.readable.pdf"
FILETMP="$1.tempfile.pdf"

# backups
#cp "$FILE" "$FILE.BAK"
# converts to readable format
qpdf -qdf "$FILE" "$FILEQDF"
# removes background
cat "$FILEQDF" | sed  '/^%% Contents for page/, /f\*/ { /^1 1 1 rg/, /f\*/ { s/^/%% /  }  }' >  "$FILETMP"
# fixes pdf
fix-qdf "$FILETMP" > "$FILE"
rm "$FILETMP"
rm "$FILEQDF"
```

Comment: +1 for taking this up again. Looks promising, but unfortunately does now work with my OpenOffice slides. (`fix-qdf: <nam>.pdf.readable.qdf: not a pdf file`)

Comment: try looking at qdf for the pdf generated by openoffice and changing the sed expression; modified the script a bit, maybe it helps

Comment: Indeed it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I used Inkscape to modify an existing PDF and selected checked background in document properties and it worked perfectly !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Inkscape worked very nicely for me as well. During import and saving, a popup was shown offering me some options, but I could leave all set to the default. It even allowed me to fix a typo in the PDF I thought was to stay there forever.